# How to reuse common Wagtail Page objects (streamfields, edit_handler, content_panels)

Tags: django, wagtail

From the demo page, I've seen reuse of common StreamBlock elements, with abstract classes that inherit from `django.Models`.

I would like to know how I can reuse a set of Wagtail Page objects. Given this model:

```
class EventPage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        HomePageStreamBlock(),
        verbose_name='main content',
        default=''
    )
    headingpanel = StreamField(
        HeadingPanelStreamBlock(),
        verbose_name='overpanel',
        default=''
    )
    sidepanel = StreamField(
        SidePanelStreamBlock(),
        verbose_name='sidepanel',
        default=''
    )

    master_event_id = models.CharField(max_length=1024, unique=True)
    creator = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    recurrence = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=200),
        null=True,
        blank=True
    )
    google_cal_url = models.URLField('Google calendar link', max_length=1024)
    calendar = models.ForeignKey(
        Calendar,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        verbose_name='Calendar',
        related_name='events',
        null=True,
        blank=False
    )

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [index.SearchField('body')]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('calendar'),
        FieldPanel('title'),
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]

    pagesection_panels = [
        StreamFieldPanel('headingpanel'),
        StreamFieldPanel('sidepanel'),
    ]

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
        ObjectList(content_panels),
        ObjectList(pagesection_panels),
        ObjectList(Page.promote_panels),
        ObjectList(Page.settings_panels, classname='settings'),
    ])
```

I would want to reuse the streamfield objects (body, headingpanel, sidepanel) and the content_panel `StreamFieldPanel('body')`, and the `edit_handler`. The only compelling reason for wanting this is the common DRY principle.

I would like to know if trying to do code reuse here is viable and worth pursuing. I don't fully understand the Django ORM and the exact way of how Wagtail implements the `Page` model. My inclination is to just keep things super basic by avoiding code reuse, to avoid potential foot shooting in the future. However a part of me feels that duplicating this much code can quickly get ugly.

If I can safely reuse this common code, what is the correct way to go about it? I've tried putting these common objects in an abstract base class, but even though nothing broke doesn't mean that it's correct and that I have not set myself up for a near future foot shooting appointment.

I've also heard of mixins, but haven't tried them out.

I would like to deploy soon. The functionality is all there, but I'd really like to have these fundamentals ironed out before committing to a production setup.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: An abstract base class is definitely the way to go - that's exactly what I was about to suggest.

Comment: You can look at answers to this question to answer part of your question i guess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538129/extending-wagtail-streamfields-in-an-inherited-class

Comment: @gasman Should I have to update the new model's `edit_handler` if this new model adds fields to `content_panels`? This has been my experience, so I want to know if I am doing it wrong. BTW, my abstract model has a custom `edit_handler`.

Comment: @jollyroger I'd need to see the code to properly understand what you mean - please open this as a new question if you'd like to take this further.

Comment: @gasman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668167/what-is-the-correct-way-to-extend-wagtail-abstract-models-with-extra-fields