# What is the correct way to extend Wagtail abstract models with extra fields?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have an abstract Wagtail model with a few `StreamField`s. Two of these `StreamField`s are in a separate tab in the admin view, which are added to the `edit_handler`.

```
class AbstractHomePage(Page):
    body = StreamField(
        HomePageStreamBlock(),
        default=''
    )
    headingpanel = StreamField(
        HeadingPanelStreamBlock(),
        default=''
    )
    sidepanel = StreamField(
        SidePanelStreamBlock(),
        default=''
    )

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [index.SearchField('body')]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body'),
    ]

    pagesection_panels = [
        StreamFieldPanel('headingpanel'),
        StreamFieldPanel('sidepanel'),
    ]

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
        ObjectList(content_panels),
        ObjectList(pagesection_panels, heading='Page sections'),
        ObjectList(Page.promote_panels),
        ObjectList(Page.settings_panels, classname='settings'),
    ])
```

I want to extend this model and add a field:

```
class Foo(AbstractHomePage):
    extra = models.TextField()

    Meta:
        verbose_name='Foo'

    content_panels = [
        AbstractHomePage.content_panels[0],     # title
        FieldPanel('extra'),
        AbstractHomePage.content_panels[-1]     # streamfield
    ]
```

When adding a new Foo page, the only fields available in the admin panel are the fields from the `AbstractHomePage`. The newly added field isn't available until I update `Foo`'s `edit_handler`:

```
class Foo(AbstractHomePage):
    extra = models.TextField()

    Meta:
        verbose_name='Foo'

    content_panels = [
        AbstractHomePage.content_panels[0],     # title
        FieldPanel('extra'),
        AbstractHomePage.content_panels[-1]     # streamfield
    ]

    edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
        ObjectList(content_panels),
        ObjectList(AbstractHomePage.pagesection_panels, heading='Page sections'),
        ObjectList(Page.promote_panels),
        ObjectList(Page.settings_panels, classname='settings'),
    ])
```

And now to my question: Have I done something wrong or not followed good coding practices?

If I do have to update the `edit_handler` for each extending model, is there a better way to do this? Having to ensure that newly added fields for models extending the `AbstractHomePage` gets the explicit "boilerplate" `edit_handler` block each time feels really ugly. I see it as a massive violation of the DRY principle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you have to redefine `edit_handler` in `Foo` is that Python evaluates the `AbstractHomePage` class definition from top to bottom - at the point that it encounters the line:

```
ObjectList(content_panels),
```

`content_panels` is treated as a variable, not a class property, and so the edit handler is built based on the `content_panels` list as it existed at that point. Redefining `content_panels` in the subclass can't override this.

Essentially, you're looking for a way to defer constructing the edit_handler until the subclass has been defined. I can't see a good way of doing that directly, but I think you could achieve it with a bit of digging into Wagtail internals, by overriding [the `Page.get_edit_handler` method](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/4f1d3509ff0f8958adb288ec53945fde76c31260/wagtail/wagtailadmin/edit_handlers.py#L738-L761):

```
from wagtail.utils.decorators import cached_classmethod

class AbstractHomePage(Page):
    ...
    @cached_classmethod
    def get_edit_handler(cls):
        edit_handler = TabbedInterface([
            ObjectList(cls.content_panels),
            ObjectList(cls.pagesection_panels, heading='Page sections'),
            ObjectList(cls.promote_panels),
            ObjectList(cls.settings_panels, classname='settings'),
        ])
        return edit_handler.bind_to_model(cls)
```

Comment: seems that ``.bind_to_model`` will be deprecated after wagtail 2.4

Comment: Use `return edit_handler.bind_to(model=cls)` in wagtail 2.5+